# Iterate over multiple array elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to iterate over multiple array elements named urls and names. Below is the code where only urls are iterated. How can I use names also with urls?

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);
app.controller('Nav', function($scope) {
      $scope.names = [
          {
            "name" : "myname 1",
          },
          {
             "name": "myname 2"
          }  
      ]
      $scope.urls = [
          {
            "url" : "http://google.com",
          },
          {
             "url": "http://cnn.com"
          }
     ]; 
});
```

HTML

```
 <body ng-controller="Nav">
    {{urls}}
    {{names}}
    <div ng-repeat="link in urls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="link.url" />
        <input type="text"  />  //Want name here
    </div> 
 </body>
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/OXXdFK2JElVaAh0uYmxG?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See answer in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OhnEpFjUVfLVUQw4TP3Z?p=preview

Add the ng-model like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="names[$index].name"/>
```

Every ng-repeat has some special properties exposed on local scope, see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

The one we are using is:

$index - iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

So as long as both arrays have the same length, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);
app.controller('Nav', function($scope) {
      $scope.names = [
          {
            "name" : "myname 1",
          },
          {
             "name": "myname 2"
          }  
      ]
      $scope.urls = [
          {
            "url" : "http://google.com",
          },
          {
             "url": "http://cnn.com"
          }
     ]; 
});
```

to 
    var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);
    app.controller('Nav', function($scope) {
          $scope.urls = [
              {
                "name" : "myname 1",
                "url" : "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                 "name": "myname 2",
                 "url": "http://cnn.com"
              }
          ]
    });

then in your HTML

```
<body ng-controller="Nav">
    <div ng-repeat="url in urls">
        <label>{{url.name}}<input type="text" ng-model="url.url" /></label>
    </div> 
  </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6ne9jetDZTt4QhPctUpq?p=preview ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marius, but that's currently not possible else would have done it.